# Laravel. Ошибка SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2053 при обработке нескольких результирующих наборов из хранимой процедуры MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, pdo

Приложение работает с базой данных через хранимые процедуры. Некоторые из них возвращают не один а несколько результирующих наборов. Проблема в том что на некоторых платформах ловлю ошибку.

Статистика работоспособности/неработоспособности:

- *CentoS 5, Apache 2.2, Php 5.6* - работает
- *Fedora 23, Apache 2.4, Php 5.6* - работает
- *CentoS 6+, Apache 2.4, Php 5.6* - ошибка
- *Ubuntu 14.04, Apache 2.4, Php 5.6* - ошибка

Ошибка следующего характера:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2053

Код обращения к базе и обработки результатов

```
$pdo = DB::connection()->getPdo();
// все имена хранимых процедур и передаваемых параметров вымышлены, любое совпадение случайно )
$dataSets = $pdo->prepare("CALL procedureName($procedureParams)");
$dataSets->execute();

// первый результирующий набор
$setSingleFirst = array($dataSets->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, 'stdClass'));
$setComplex = [
    'setSingleFirst' => $setSingleFirst[0]
];

$dataSets->nextRowset();

// второй результирующий набор
$setSingleSecond = array($dataSets->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, 'stdClass'));
$setComplex += [
    'setSingleSecond' => $setSingleSecond[0]
];

return $setComplex;
```

Во время отладки обнаружил что `$setSingleFirst` получаю, и он содержит все необходимые данные, а вот на получении `$setSingleSecond` получаю ошибку.

В чем причина того что на одних платформах все отрабатывает корректно, а на других нет. версии *Php* одинаковые, модули одни и теже. настройки те же.

Comment: смотрите, что [возвращает execute()](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22423763/4827341)

Comment: Можно попросить добавить в статистику наличие-отсутствие mysqlnd?

Answer (score 1):

[Хранимая процедура всегда возвращает дополнительный пустой результат](http://phpdelusions.net/pdo#call). Но если попытаться этот результат прочитать, то получим ошибку. В качестве воркараунда можно использовать `PDOStatement::columnCount()`:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("CALL procedureName(?)");
$stmt->execute([$procedureParams]);
$setSingleFirst = [];
do {
    $setSingleFirst[] = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
} while ($stmt->nextRowset() && $stmt->columnCount());
```

Заодно почистил код. Отдельно доставило засовывание результата в массив, чтобы тут же вытащить из него обратно.

Comment: использование Вашего примера кода не исправило ситуацию, ошибка осталось. Однако я обратил внимание на ваш коментарий относительно mysqlnd. Замена php5-mysql на php5-mysqlnd - решило проблему.